# where can I find the default value for this storm configurable `topology.worker.timeout.secs`

Tags: apache-storm

I find the declaration here: https://github.com/apache/storm/blob/3f96c249cbc17ce062491bfbb39d484e241ab168/storm-client/src/jvm/org/apache/storm/Config.java#L1161
but could not find its default value from the yaml (https://github.com/apache/storm/blob/b6e7d0355e0397b8acc566961ed31279338998e1/conf/defaults.yaml).
I am trying to tune this parameter in my setup but need to figure out what is a "recommended" value to start with.

Comment: if my answer was helpful, I would be happy if you could accept the question. :)

Comment: Sure, I am going to start with the `worker. max.timeout_secs` configuration instead, since I don't find the reference of `topology.worker.timeout.secs` throughout the code base either.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The comment on `topology.worker.timeout.secs` says:

> Topology configurable worker heartbeat timeout before the supervisor
> tries to restart the worker process. Maximum value constrained by
> `WORKER_MAX_TIMEOUT_SECS`. When topology timeout is greater, the
> following configs are effectively overridden:
> `SUPERVISOR_WORKER_TIMEOUT_SECS`, `SUPERVISOR_WORKER_START_TIMEOUT_SECS`,
> `NIMBUS_TASK_TIMEOUT_SECS` and `NIMBUS_TASK_LAUNCH_SECS`.

As I can not find a default value for that as well, I had a look into `nimbus.java`:

```java
if (mergedConf.containsKey(Config.TOPOLOGY_WORKER_TIMEOUT_SECS)) {
  int workerTimeoutSecs = (Integer) ObjectReader.getInt(mergedConf.get(Config.TOPOLOGY_WORKER_TIMEOUT_SECS));
  int workerMaxTimeoutSecs = (Integer) ObjectReader.getInt(mergedConf.get(Config.WORKER_MAX_TIMEOUT_SECS));
  if (workerTimeoutSecs > workerMaxTimeoutSecs) {
      ret.put(Config.TOPOLOGY_WORKER_TIMEOUT_SECS, workerMaxTimeoutSecs);
      ...
  }
}
```

But this key is not contained anywhere, and when I am debugging through nimbus and evaluate that config, I get `null`, meaning, that this value is never set.

**Looking at `WORKER_MAX_TIMEOUT_SECS` gives 600 seconds in `default.yaml`, so I think this might serve as a starting point for you.**